# Conditional/delayed mailing with resque?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, resque

I got an application that creates loads of PDF documents which, sometimes take some time to create, hence I moved all the PDF creation to a resque background job. However, some PDFs need also to be sent out by mail which now is a problem because I don't know how to tell the mailer to wait for the PDFs to be created.

Before I had this:

```
@contract.create_invoice
ContractMailer.send_invoice(@contract).deliver
```

Now I have this:

```
Resque.enqueue(InvoiceCreator, @contract)
ContractMailer.send_invoice(@contract).deliver
```

So ContractMailer always fails because the pdf is not yet created. Anyone has an idea how to solve this elegantly?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you thought about having the job that created the PDF enqueue the mail job at the end of creation?

Comment: Yes but some mails have 2 or 3 files attached so that approach unfortunately doesn't work.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?